# Date column grouping header links to page with date format incorrect and no results shown

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, grouping, date

I have a SharePoint Online list using the Modern view that I have grouped by a date column. When showing the list of groups everything appears fine. However, when I click the group header to view all of the items for that particular date, the date format is butchered, which causes no results to appear.

This seems to happen on all of the SharePoint lists that I have tried this on, which includes two separate SharePoint Online environments. Is this a known issue? Is there a way to correct the formatting so the results are shown?

The regional settings are English - United States. The same thing happens regardless if the column is a Date column or a Date/Time column.

---

Screenshot of grouped view - date format is correct and two results are shown:
[image: Date grouping headers - format is correct]

---

Screenshot of what the date format looks like when clicking on the header - date format is mangled and no results are shown:
[image: Clicking on header shows page with format mangled and no results shown]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue if I use group and filter together with date column in UI, which you means clicking on the header.

[image]

As a workaround, I suggest you group the data column in list settings>Views>Group By.

[image]

It works well when you set this via list settings.

[image]

You could also submit a feedback in the [SharePoint UserVoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/) forum and report this issue.

Comment: Your answer helped me, but the actual fix was changing my view settings to show groups as collapsed by default, as I already had my view set up with groupings in the view definition. I will submit on UserVoice, thanks for the tip.